# iPhone :: xmppframework - Retrieve Complete Roster

Tags: iphone, xmpp, xmppframework

I am half way through implementing my xmpp chatting module on iPhone using xmppframework library, having a little question here.

Based on some examples, I have done it this way:
- Once I am connected and authenticated, in the `xmppStreamDidAuthenticate` delegate, I will send my presence.
- And I will receive my roster presence in `didReceivePresence` delegate.

The problem is that I am now only receiving presence from all my online roster, but not the offline roster. How is it possible to request for a complete list of my roster?

I found there is a `fetchRoster` method in `XMPPRoster` class, but I have no idea how it should be called, and what should be the delegate for receiving the incoming roster information.

Comment: I have ended up create a separate webservice method to retrieve my complete list of roster. Would still appreciate if anyone has a suggestion of how this can be achieved with xmppframework directly without webservice. :)

Answer (score 7):

To retrive the roster directly in xmppframework try this:

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
    NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];

if (queryElement) {
    NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
    [ArrayUsers removeAllObjects];
    for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++) {

        NSString *jid=[[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
        [ArrayUsers addObject:jid];
    }



 }


 return NO;
}
```

You will find didReceiveIQ in the AppDelegate method. In this way you will have at each login a complete list of your roster. Next if you want refresh for some reason this list you can try this:

```
 NSXMLElement *queryElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];

NSXMLElement *iqStanza = [NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"iq"];
[iqStanza addAttributeWithName: @"type" stringValue: @"get"];
[iqStanza addChild: queryElement];

[xmppStream sendElement: iqStanza];
```

Comment: is it possible to for any particular roster ? i want status of roster (available / away / offline)

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you. [How to list only online users on facebook with xmpp framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300912/how-to-list-only-online-users-on-facebook-with-xmpp-framework) With some modifications, code mentioned in this post should work for you.